Combine WhatsApp messages on new phone and old phone
I just switched my wife's phone from a Pixel 4a to a Pixel 8, and used the USB cable method to copy data. Prior to initiating the transfer I forced a backup of WhatsApp chats to Google Drive.
However, the entire transfer process took over an hour, during which time new messages came in to the old phone. The entire history with the exception of these new messages appears to have restored to the new phone.
Is there any way to recover and transfer these last few messages from the couple of past hours?

You can [tag:factory-reset] Pixel 8,insert SIM into Pixel 4, authenticate Whatsapp and repeat the transfer process, this time with 4a in Airplane mode (ensure not connected to Wifi also) //Time consuming, yes// Before that, Also force backup to GDrive so that you can restore

@beeshyams, shouldn't this be an answer?

It also can become a circular problem @rohit... What if they get msgs on 8 meanwhile?

I was thinking of doing what @beeshyams suggested, but I had the same concern that we would then lose the new messages that were already on the 8. I'm not sure why I didn't put the 4a in airplane mode before starting, even though I considered it at the time. Just one of those dumb mistakes we make. I just wish the instructions given by WhatsApp would mention this. It's not the first time I messed this up (but last time was a few years ago so of course I forgot).
